# Login is not working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In the checkout page, I'm making a check to see it the user is logged in and if he's not, then a pop up window appears with log in details. The log in form that I pop up is from the file **customer/form/mini.login.phtml**. However when I press the submit button nothing at all happens. With a little search I found out that I need to add the form_key in the mini.login.phtml file. So the code snippet I'm adding is:

```
 <input name="form_key" type="hidden"
 value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

I use **Ctrl+R** to reload the page and remove the cache but still nothing happens.

Any hint would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Did you check your browser network tab and console tab? Is ther any issue occured?

Comment: Well on the network tab nothing at all occurs when I hit the submit button. Console throws some errors but after examining them I didn't find any connection with this form

Comment: Then your <form> tag in your html code. Also double check the submit button should be placed with in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your  `customer/form/mini.login.phtml` and find this line  `<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post">` 
add below code after this line

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
```

Remember clean the cache and refresh page and check.

Comment: Unfortunately,  no change at all....does it have to do anything with the fact that it is in a pop up ?

Comment: Well eventually I used another Magento's login form. I used it's ID to catch it with jQuery and that's it.